# PHP - C# translated hashing function not working?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, rfc

I'll get right to the question,

We have this block of C# code

```
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, passwordSaltBytes, iterationCount))
 {
   pbkdf2Bytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(derivedLength + iterationCountBytes.Length);         
 }
```

> Returns a byte array, first index has a value of 252

We attempt the same thing in PHP:

```
$key = hash_pbkdf2("SHA1", $password, $password.$salt, $iterationCount, 48);
```

> First index is 102...

The values all match before this specific part.

It's just that hashing function that isn't giving me consistent results.

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

**Edit** - If it's not obvious, I'm trying to understand why those two values don't match, what encoding/decoding etc. am I misunderstanding or doing incorrectly.

Comment: pbkdf1 includes sha1 (backwards compatibility) while pbkdf2 doesn't.  See : http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2898.txt.  Also see posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068133/importance-of-the-key-size-in-the-rfc2898derivebytes-pbkdf2-implementation

Comment: I answered a suspiciously familiar question yesterday.  First thing you'll notice if you read the docs for `hash_pbkdf2` is that it outputs hex and not raw data unless you set `$raw_output` to true.  The reason you get 102 is because 102 is encoded to the character f in ASCII/UTF8.  See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php

Comment: @BarryD. Why `$password.$salt` and not `$salt`?

Comment: @LukePark The person you had a back and forth with wasn't the OP. But we know you got tired of helping and deleted your comment, not sure why you bothered posting here - you're free to delete those comments too btw.

Comment: @ArtjomB. because the C# script joins the two and passes it in as `passwordSaltBytes`, and upon analysing those bytes, I get the same result in PHP when I do $password.$salt and then read their bytes.

Comment: @LukePark Your answer is actually correct. But when a person asks something, please understand that they're asking because they don't know, not for you to get frustrated at them. All you had to do was show an example or something. We don't all catch on to things the same way.

Comment: @BarryD I did show and demonstrate a very straight forward method to produce the exact same result in both languages. I deleted my answer, not out of frustration, but due to the number of un-useful comments (22) underneath. And yes, my answer is correct, as it was when I first wrote it.  You're welcome.

Comment: @LukePark "You're welcome" - I like how you assume you were the one who solved this issue. I said your answer is correct, and had your character been a little better with the person who asked that question, I'm sure you would have made their day. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full C# code. As you can see there are some unnecessary loops etc. but the reasons why this wasn't working are 2:

1. As somebody pointed out, the bytes in PHP do no output raw data by default, and thus the hash (and consequently as such,) its bytes, weren't identical with that of the C# script.
2. Previously, I thought (as others also pointed out) that I should pass in the `$salt` as it is without any encoding or transformation. But upon looking closer at the actual C# code... we can see in the 2nd `for i` loop that they're actually appending `saltBytes` onto `passwordBytes`, thus creating something similar to `$password.$salt` in PHP

Combining the two above issues:

- Sending the `$password.$salt` instead of just one, and then setting the `$raw_output` option to true, outputs the same hash, the same bytes as C# does.

  ```
      byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
      byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
      byte[] iterationCountBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(iterationCount);
      int derivedLength = passwordBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length;
      byte[] passwordSaltBytes = new byte[derivedLength];
      byte[] pbkdf2Bytes;
      string encryptedString;


      for (int i = 0; i < passwordBytes.Length; i++)
      {
          passwordSaltBytes[i] = passwordBytes[i];
      }


      for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
      {
          passwordSaltBytes[passwordBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];
      }

      using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, passwordSaltBytes, iterationCount))
      {
          pbkdf2Bytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(derivedLength + iterationCountBytes.Length);


      }
  ```

Thanks.